# Created following query, Use 2 pivot for income and profit,But want order like 1 st column of profit then 1 st column of income

Tags: sql-server

[image]

PIVOT Query:

```
Declare @cols nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols= COALESCE (@cols+',['+shipmentmonth+' Profit]','['+shipmentmonth+' Profit]') from (select distinct  shipmentmonth from  MargaritaSales where ShipYearMonth >='201601'  ) P   
Declare @cols1 nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols1= COALESCE (@cols1+',['+shipmentmonth+' Income]','['+shipmentmonth+' Income]') from (select distinct  shipmentmonth from  MargaritaSales where ShipYearMonth >='201601'  ) P1   
    --Declare @cols nvarchar(max)
    --SELECT @cols= COALESCE (@cols+',['+shipmentmonth+' Profit]'+'['+shipmentmonth+' Income]','['+shipmentmonth+' Profit]'+'['+shipmentmonth+' Income]') from (select distinct  shipmentmonth from  MargaritaSales where ShipYearMonth >='201601'  ) P 

--select @cols

 DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @query =
'SELECT * 
 FROM ( SELECT  T.buyer,T.buyerid, T.shipmentmonth,T.shipmentmonth+ 
''Income'' as shipmentmonth1,
    (t.PROFIT +t.USDServiceIncome -t.USDServiceExpense) as Profit1,
    ( t.Income+t.OfficeIncome+t.USDServiceIncome) as Income1 
    FROM    MargaritaSales  T  where T.ShipYearMonth >=''201601'') up PIVOT 
    (sum(PROFIT1)  
    FOR shipmentmonth IN ('+ @cols +')) AS pvt1

    PIVOT (sum(Income1)   
            FOR shipmentmonth1 IN (+ @cols1 + ')) AS pvt2'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want. Please explain what you want to achieve, post your table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: I tried to reformulate your question, it is so hard to understand what is your question here. Review the edit and accept if it is what you are asking

Comment: I am added screenshot ,this is output of query.in which it show all profit column first then all income column,But i want 1 st colum of profit then 1 st column of income , e.g june 18 profit,june 18 income,july 18 profit ,july 18 income.

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to use `CASE STATEMENT` for such case rather than `PIVOT`

this is how it is looks like. You need to convert to Dynamic Query as per what you did with PIVOTing

```
SELECT  T.buyer, T.buyerid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ShipYearMonth = 201601 THEN t.PROFIT + t.USDServiceIncome -t.USDServiceExpense END) as Profit1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ShipYearMonth = 201601 THEN t.Income + t.OfficeIncome + t.USDServiceIncome) as Income1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ShipYearMonth = 201602 THEN t.PROFIT + t.USDServiceIncome -t.USDServiceExpense END) as Profit2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ShipYearMonth = 201602 THEN t.Income + t.OfficeIncome + t.USDServiceIncome) as Income2
FROM    MargaritaSales T  
WHERE   T.ShipYearMonth >= 201601
GROUP BY T.buyer, T.buyerid
```

Comment: it is dynamic report , when will run this report in November 18, then also it need to give result

Comment: just change to dynamic as what you done currently using sp_executesql